# Stored procedure: Select by matching input parameter or return the null records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following case:

There is a table like this:

```
Id     | Param  | Value
------ | ------ | -------------
1      | 1      | One 1
1      | NULL   | Null-Value 1
1      | 2      | Two 1
1      | 3      | Three 3
2      | NULL   | Nul-Value 2
2      | 2      | Two 2
3      | NULL   | Null-Value 3
4      | 1      | One 4
5      | NULL   | Null-Vaue  5
6      | NULL   | Null-Value 6
```

I have to write a stored procedure as by given input nullable parameter for "Param" I have to generate a result which will contain a table with ID and Value and the result is based on the logic -

**If the input parameter is null - return all rows with null values for Param**

**If the parameter is not null, then return the rows which match that parameter in the Param column and also all rows (for the other IDs), which have null value as Param.**

**There MUST be only ONE result per Id**.

*Consider that there is applied an unique composite index on the Id and Param columns.*

**Example:**

```
Input parameter: 1

Output table:

Id | Value
-- | -------------
1  | One 1
2  | Nul-Value 2
3  | Null-Value 3
4  | One 4
5  | Null-Vaue  5
6  | Null-Value 6
```

**Example 2 (let me include the Param column as well for better visibility):**

```
Input parameter: 2

Output table:

Id | Param | Value
-- | ----- |-------------
1  | 2     |Two 1
2  | 2     |Two 2
3  | NULL  |Null-Value 3
5  | NULL  |Null-Value 5
6  | NULL  |Null-Value 6
```

---

- I suppose it will be a join of the table with itself, or even better with cross(or maybe outer) apply and some proper where clause...

Comment: What have you written so far?   What error are you getting?

Comment: Something like this: 

select t.Id, t.MyParam, t.MyValue
from [dbo].[MyTable] t
outer apply (select * from MyTable t2
    where t2.MyParam = @ input
    and t.Id = t2.Id
    and t.MyParam = t2.MyParam) mt

where (mt.MyParam = @ input and t.MyParam is not null) or  t.MyParam is null

But it returns also the NULL value for Id 1 (the rest is ok)

Comment: outer apply makes me cry.

Comment: We don't put "SOLVED" in the title.  Especially when the selected answer is so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the query:

```
declare @input int = 2

select t.Id, t.Value
from [dbo].[MyTable] t
outer apply (select * from MyTable t2
             where t2.Param = @input
             and t.Id = t2.Id) mt
where  (t.Id = mt.Id and t.Param = @input)
or (t.Param is null and mt.Param is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem with multiple results per id.  You don't give any rules for which one you want per id so I can't do the next step.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableyoudidnotsaythenameof as x
WHERE (coalesce(x.value, @inparam) = @inparam) or
      (@inparam is null and x.value is null)
```

if you don't care which one you return when there is more than one per id this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by id) as rn
  FROM tableyoudidnotsaythenameof as x
  WHERE (coalesce(x.value, @inparam) = @inparam) or
        (@inparam is null and x.value is null)
) zed
WHERE zed.rn = 1
```

---

to sort nulls with bigger rn:

```
  SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by id order by CASE WHEN x.value is null then 2 else 1 END) as rn
```

Comment: it should have only one result per id since there is a unique index applied on the ID and Param, so it will match either with the null as Pram or with the input parameter. 
The above example will not work for input parameter different than 1 and null

Comment: @peev -- sure it will.  did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I just replaced the name of the table with mine, instead of x.value - x.param, and I put one "order by id" in the (partition by id) because it is required.

Comment: @peev -- it is a mystery what output do you expect for 2 and how is that different from what you get?

Comment: "return the rows which match that parameter in the Param column and also all rows, which have null value as Param" - return table with rows, which have Param = @ inparam and those with Param = null.
See above, I've updated the question post

Comment: @peev -- this is what my code does.  Honest!  I've been writing SQL for over 20 years and first solved this problem 15 years ago.

Comment: It will not work for some cases, because the query will get only the top 1 per each duplicated records and if the first is with the null value - it will return the row with the null value for param, instead of the matching one. It is tested. Maybe the solution of this query is the result first to be sorted by param, to be sure that the null will be always below the match. 
Thanks for the answer though, it is a very good example of useful staff and techniques!

Comment: as I said in my answer "if you don't care which one you return".  If you do then add an `ORDER BY` clause to the ROW_NUMBER() row.  This should be **significantly** faster than an outer apply.   It is also the case that your outer apply solution will not scale.  So in a few months you will back here to ask why it is running slow.

Comment: I said in my question - "If the parameter is not null, then return the rows which match that parameter in the Param column" You didn't provide the needed query at that moment. Then I realized it can be useful and that's why I voted for it but already applied my solution. So it is a bit incorrect to vote negative for mine working perfectly fine for my needs and small table solution.

Comment: @peev, ok I added in the code to "remove" the nulls in the output.  I also think it is impolite to accuse me of downvoting -- since you have no way to know who downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one without the use of joins. When @param is null it returns all rows.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT, [Param] INT, Val VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 1,' One 1'),
(1, NULL,'Null-Value 1'),
(1, 2,'Two 1'),
(1, 3,'Three 3'),
(2,NULL,'Nul-Value 2'),
(2, 2,'One 2'),
(3, NULL,'Null-Value 3'),
(4, 1,'One 4'),
(5, NULL,'Null-Vaue 5'),
(6, NULL,'Null-Value 6')

DECLARE @Param INT
SET @Param = 1

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE @Param IS NULL OR (([Param] = @Param) OR ([Param] IS NULL AND Id <> @Param))
```

Comment: if @Param is null this just returns all rows